# Making far objects look fading or transparent

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a 3D rectangle, rotated 45 degrees as in the attached screenshot. I would like the lines and the far edge (A) to look fading. Moreover, when i rotate the camera, i want the 'new' far lines and edges to look fading. So if B will be in the place if A, B and the lines to B will look fading. How can i do that?

If it makes any difference, i use OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest enabling alpha blending and in your pixel shader you set the resulting color's alpha value based on the depth.
Something like `result.a = clamp(1.0/(-gl_FragCoord.z + 1.0), 0.0, 1.0)` might work.